# Log4net inside BHO does not work?

Tags: c#, log4net, bho, ieaddon

I'm trying to use log4net with an external config file, but it does not work: nothing gets logged

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>   
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="C:\\tmp\\test.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />

        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
         <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

If I use this line in Assembly.cs, test.lg is creatd when the BHO is registered with regasm, but not when the plugin is running:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = @"C:\\tmp\\test.log4net", Watch = true)]
```

When I use this code inside the BHO, no log is adde to test.log:

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\\tmp\\test.log4net"));
log.Info("test");
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log4net configuration file was fine. The problem is that Internet Explorer ran in Protected Mode, which forbids BHOs to write to arbitrary folders. There are only a few folders where the BHO can write.